# Getting events of other user as an Admin

Tags: box-api

I have enterprise box admin privileges. How can I get a User's events. I see this on my web "Admin Console" (Report).

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/events -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=....&auth_token=....."
```

The above command just gives my events not the enterprise level events.

Thanks in Advance
-Praveen

Answer (score 0):

There isn't yet something like this in `v2`, however, we have an unreleased method from `v1` that should help with this use case.